# hibernate `cache usage` parameter programmatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I'm currently configuring hibernate to use ehcache and provide a `CacheManager` programmatically. We do not use hibernate.xml nor ehcache.xml as we have our own configuration service to provide such informataion.

Now I'm facing an issue: where must the configuration `cache usage` be defined programmatically?

I'd like to activate it when I create the `CacheConfiguration` if it is possible but I do not find a method that allows setting the property.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?14968-Share-cache-manager-with-hibernate) post can help here.

all you need to do afer writing the code by "F.Degenaar" is, while creating the session factory, create a `java.util.Properties` object add the property (key) `hibernate.cache.provider_class` and value the fully qualified class name with the `EhCacheProvider`.

--edit

you can add the objects to cache manually, as far as programatically settting something to be cached or not is concerned, its gonna be quite difficult as the annotations are at compile time, Id recommend you to use the annotation and programatically cache/avoid caching queries and results.

Comment: Hi, what you mention is to configure the cache provider. Howver, a caching strategy needs to be configured per entity (possible with the <cache usage="read-only/read-write/etc"> and also with the annotation @Cache). I'd like to insert that property programmatically, depending on my configuration

Comment: you can add the objects to cache manually, as far as programatically settting something to be cached or not is concerned, its gonna be quite difficult as the annotations are at compile time, Id recommend you to use the annotation and programatically cache/avoid caching queries and results.

Comment: I consider your response off topic but your comment is my answer, but cannot mark a comment as the accepted response

Comment: adjusted answer, added the comment part as the answer, probably now you can accept it. ;)